# modify every element of collection

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Is there any common way to get rid of custom 'assign' functor? std::transform could be great but according to c++ standard it prohibits modification of the source elements

The goal is to modify collection elements using as more declarative approach as possible

```
template <typename T>
struct assign : std::binary_function<T, T, void> {
    void operator()( const T& source, T& dest ) {
        dest = source;
    }
};

int main() {
    static boost::array<int, 5> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::for_each( arr.begin(), arr.end(), 
        boost::bind( assign<int>(), boost::bind( std::plus<int>(), _1, 3 ), _1 ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good question.  Modifying every element would allow conversion in-place of text strings to all lower case or all upper case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std::transform() does allow the output iterator to point to the same element as the beginning of your input range.  See [here](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/).  The code example shows essentially this in the line demonstrating a transform with two input ranges. The output iterator is the same as the first input iterator.  Does that make it more palatable?

Comment: yep, this works. But the standard says ( see 25.3.4 Transform ): ... op and binary_op shall not invalidate iterators or subranges, or modify elements in the ranges [first1,last1] ...

Comment: That doesn't modify the elements, it replaces them. This doesn't invalidate the iterators.

Comment: It modifies what's where the iterator points to, no the iterator itself. The new value will still be pointed to by the very same iterator.

Comment: it seems a bit strange to me that there is a difference between modification and replacing. Is there any reference to check it?

Comment: yep, I'm bothered not about iterators but the elements they are pointed to. I'm intrested in interpretation of the quote from the standard "op ... shall not ... modify elements in the ranges [first1,last1] ..."

Comment: @Voivoid: That same sentence also says "shall not .. modify elements in the ranges ... [result,result + (last1 - first1)]". Of course the `result` range gets modified so I question how that sentence is worded. In addition, the _Remarks_ state that `result` may be equal to `first`. I believe the language is simply confusing and the std::transform algorithm has always been able to transform _in place_.

Answer (score 2):

Try Boost.Lambda:

```
int main() {
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    static boost::array<int, 5> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::for_each( arr.begin(), arr.end(), _1 += 3 );
    return 0;
}
```

However, what about just a "for_each" loop:

```
int main() {
    static boost::array<int, 5> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    BOOST_FOREACH(int& n, arr) {
        n += 3;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. boost::lambda looks nice. BOOST_FOREACH is also great but it  doesn't allow to specify the needed sequence with the pair of iterators. Still i wonder if std::transform could be used to modify input sequence. Any comments would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What @gregg said plus:

The wording in the standard (N1905 25.2.3 paragraph 2) forbids the transformation function from directly modifying elements in the given ranges, i.e. it cannot write to an input iterator. It is only supposed to calculate a value, which the `transform` function then assigns to the `result` iterator. In fact, paragraph 5 explicitly allows `result` to be equal to `first`.

I guess this may allow implementations to perform safety-checks or optimizations in specific cases.

For instance, suppose `transform` were specialized for `std::vector<char>`. On a 32 bit machine, the implementation could unroll the main loop 4 times and perform 32 bit loads and stores instead of 8 bit ones. Clearly this would not work, if the first call to the transformation function modified the input range (the remaining 3 calls before the store would then operate on dirty data).

Here's C++03 one-liner to add 3 to each value off `arr`:

`std::transform(arr.begin(), arr.end(), arr.begin(), std::bind1st(std::plus<int>(), 3));`